# Forms are not displayed in evince viewer

Tags: pdftex, forms

I'm using eforms package to make form. I have read the documentation and copied the same as in the doc but the form are not displayed in `evince` or in `okular`.
The form are displayed in adobe reader but I can't save them (I must print them).

The strange thing is that the form examples in eforms doc are displayed in `evince`. I'm missing something? How to do to get the form displayed in evince.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eforms}

\begin{document}
 \begin{Form}
  \textField
      [\Ff{\FfMultiline}\BC{0 0 1}\BG{1 1 1}
       \textColor{0 0 0}\textSize{12}
      ]{name}{11cm}{5cm}
 \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

**Note**

I can't use Adobe Reader.

Comment: You can easily create fillable forms in TeX which display as forms in Okular (and presumably evince) and can be completed and saved. My guess is that the problem is a function of `eforms` peculiar dependence on Adobe-specific features. Also, I can perfectly understand not wishing to use `acroread` but I'm a bit mystified by the claim that you *can't* do so. It is true that the version for Linux doesn't have the latest features but it should work fine for anything else. Or are you on BSD, say?

Comment: No, I can't install it because I have a 64bits system and `acroread` is not available for this platform. I can't install the 32bits version because Ubuntu drooped the 32 bits packages necessary for it.

Comment: Oh. That's too bad as it runs fine on a 64 bit system. (That's what I have but my distro provides the 32 bit packages it requires.) You can still use the forms support provided by e.g. Okular, though. That doesn't require anything additional. Just we don't know which features of forms you need. Your MWE is easily supported - I use multiline text fields in PDF forms all the time and they come up fine in Okular. (Just you have to click the button to enable form filling but that's all.) I just don't do it with `eforms`.

Answer (score 3):

`eForm`is a part of the AcroTeX bundle. As far as I remember, it depends heavily on a lot of special PDF features. Many of them have not been integrated into open source viewers like okular and evince.

You seem to be on Linux. I disreagarded the warnings and installed Acrobat Reader there. Under wine even Acrobat Pro works.

But if you can't use one of them, maybe you go and look for another solution, which is independent from AcroTeX. If you provide a minimal working example and a question, you'll almost sure will get help here.

Comment: Thanks I will try to install it under Wine. But the weired thing is that the forms of `eform` manual works in evince but not mines.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but you seem to use `\begin{Form}` and `\End{Form}` and this might not be required.

See the minimalistic example from the `eforms` manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eforms} % <-- the driver is pdftex or xetex
\begin{document}
    % Content containing form fields, such as...
    Don’t \pushButton[\CA{Push Me}]{myButton}{}{12bp},
    I fall down easily.
\end{document}
```

Search for `{Form}` in the manual to see the alternative example.